# Prove/Disprove question on matrix vector multiplication and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If $\left\{Bv_1, \ldots , Bv_k\right\}$ is a linearly independent set in $\mathbb{R}^k$ where $B$ is a $k \times n$ matrix, then $\left\{v_1, \ldots ,v_k\right\}$ is a linearly independent set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

How would I start this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\left\{\vec{v}_i\right\}_{i=1}^k$ is not linearly independent. Then, there is a set of (not all zero) constants $a_1, \ldots, a_k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \vec{v}_i = \vec{0}$. Then,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k a_i (B \vec{v}_i) = B \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \vec{v}_i = \vec{0}.
$$

Hence we found a set of not all zero constants $a_1, \ldots, a_k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k a_i (B \vec{v}_i) = \vec{0},
$$
which implies the vectors $B \vec{v}_1, \ldots, B \vec{v}_k$ are linearly *dependent*. This is a contradiction.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this is a contradiction. Doesn't ∑ai(Bvi) = 0 already because it's given that the set is linearly independent in the hypothesis of the question?

Comment: @Ryan please see the update, i spelled it out for you

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Suppose you have a linear relation between $v_1,\dots,v_k$. Transform this linear relation by $B$.